# http.createServer() vs http.request()

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, server

I think I understand this below code:

```
var assert =require("assert");
var http = require("http");

var server = http.createServer(function(req, res){
    res.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type" : "text/HTML"});
    res.write("hello, world.\r\n");
    res.end();
});
server.listen(8000, function(){
    console.log("Listening on port 8000");
});
```

We create a server and set it up to listen on port 8000 and when i go to page localhost:8000 in the browser I think it initiates a request to the server for something(can someone help me specify what that is) then the server responds with a header and "hello world"

the next part I'm not so sure of:

```
var req = http.request({
    port : 8000
}, function(res){
    console.log("HTTP header:", res.headers);
    res.on("data", function(data){
        console.log("Body:", data.toString());
        assert.equal("hello, world.\r\n", data.toString());
        assert.equal(200, res.statusCode);
        // server.unref(); //client disconnected...sever stop listening
    })
})
 req.end()
```

^^^ Is this server sending a request to the browser
I know the doc says

> Node maintains several connections per server to make HTTP requests. This function allows one to transparently issue requests.

does that mean that server is sending a request. you could randomly send a request to a client? and if so how does it get the data? Doesn't there have to be some type of initiation from the browser/ client to send over the data **how does res.on("data" ) get the data?**

Comment: The `http.request()` API is for when you want your *server* code to act as a *client* and request content from another site.

Comment: it should probably be called _HttpClient_ http.client() _HttpClient_ contains get, post, put, etc

Comment: No, a server cannot send a request to a client. There's no browser involved here. Just some node.js code opening a server and then sending a ("client") request to there.